# ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.sessions'

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, django-contrib

This app works fine in my development environment, but on my PythonAnywhere instance there seems to be an issue with Django. Any idea what could cause this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cvcexport/genius/genius/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 118, in create
    cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib' has no attribute 'sessions'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/cvcexport/genius/genius/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/cvcexport/genius/genius/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/cvcexport/genius/genius/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/cvcexport/genius/genius/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/cvcexport/genius/genius/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 123, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/home/cvcexport/genius/genius/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.sessions'
```

Comment: Could someone help me improve this question? I don't understand what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must have been an issue with this particular version of Django (`1.10.5`) as updating to `1.10.8` seems to have resolved it.