# Trying to Deploy My Django Rest API on Python Anywhere; keep receiving ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.sessions'

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

I trying to deploy my django-rest-framework api on PythonAnywhere.com, but I keep receiving django.contrib.session cannot be found.

**I have read the documentation on PythonAnywher.com, and did the following the steps:(https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject)
(https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError)

1. was able to run the wsgi.py file itself
2. was able to run import myproject.settings without error
3. was able to run python /path/to/myapp/settings.py with out error
4. Was not able to figure out what they meant by Shadowing. All the packages are imported in the virutalenv through pipfile
5. was able to verify Check virtualenv Python versions was correct**

Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'its a secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
     'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'menus',
    'login',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
     'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chefsBackEnd.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chefsBackEnd.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# DATABASES = {}
# DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)




# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator'},
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

SITE_ID = 1

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',

        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )

}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    # 'http://localhost:3000',
    # 'http://localhost:5000',

    'https://chefs-table-mock-site.herokuapp.com',
    'https://git.heroku.com/phlog-api.git'

]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'chefsBackEnd.utils.resp_handler',
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
}

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"




> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
> line 118, in create
>     cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
> **AttributeError: module 'django.contrib' has no attribute 'sessions'** During handling of the above exception, another exception
> occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line
> 21, in <module>
>     main()   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 401, in execute_f rom_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 377, in execute
>     django.setup()   File "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
> line 24, in setup
>     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
> line 91, in populate
>     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
> line 136, in create
>     import_module(entry)   File "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py",
> line 127, in import_module
>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.sessions'**
```

Based on this [ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.sessions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791493/importerror-no-module-named-django-contrib-sessions), they were able to change the version of django to one I have to make it run, but I keep running into the same problem.

> This must have been an issue with this particular version of Django (1.10.5) as updating to 1.10.8 seems to have resolved it. -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791493/importerror-no-module-named-django-contrib-sessions

Also, this is from the ***error logs*** on PythonAnywhere.com:

```
> 2020-07-08 19:54:28,687: Not Found: /favicon.ico 2020-07-08
> 21:27:50,215: Not Found: /static/admin/css/fonts.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:05,154: Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:05,157: Not Found: /static/admin/css/login.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:05,194: Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:15,815: Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:15,819: Not Found: /static/admin/css/login.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:15,825: Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:26,680: Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:26,685: Not Found: /static/admin/css/login.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:26,689: Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css 2020-07-08
> 21:31:36,012: Not Found: /api 2020-07-08 21:34:15,458: Not Found:
> /static/admin/css/fonts.css 2020-07-08 21:37:24,180: Not Found:
> /static/admin/css/fonts.css 2020-07-10 22:25:10,104: Error running
> WSGI application 2020-07-10 22:25:10,124: ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'django.contrib.sessions' 2020-07-10 22:25:10,124:   File
> "/var/www/jgartsu12_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
> 2020-07-10 22:25:10,124:     application = get_wsgi_application()
> 2020-07-10 22:25:10,124:  2020-07-10 22:25:10,124:   File
> "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py",
> line 12, in get_wsgi_application 2020-07-10 22:25:10,125:    
> django.setup(set_prefix=False) 2020-07-10 22:25:10,125:  2020-07-10
> 22:25:10,125:   File
> "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
> line 24, in setup 2020-07-10 22:25:10,125:    
> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) 2020-07-10 22:25:10,125: 
> 2020-07-10 22:25:10,125:   File
> "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
> line 91, in populate 2020-07-10 22:25:10,125:     app_config =
> AppConfig.create(entry) 2020-07-10 22:25:10,125:  2020-07-10
> 22:25:10,126:   File
> "/home/jgartsu12/.virtualenvs/chefsBackEnd-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
> line 136, in create 2020-07-10 22:25:10,126:     import_module(entry)
```

Comment: If you start a bash console in your virtualenv (using the link on the "Web" page inside PythonAnywhere), and run `pip show django`, what does it display?

Comment: @GilesThomas it shows:Name: Django  3.08. However, the issue pertained to the path of the file system. Check answer below! Thank you for your help!

Comment: OK, glad to hear you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

The way the files were arranged caused the program to fail to find the given modules.
To fix the problem, I had to take my code, and put it on the PythonAnywhere.com directly. Now, my api is up and running.jgartsu12.pythonanywhere.com